# Running supremmum of a Levy process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

Let X be a cadlag Lévy process with $X_0=0$ and let $p$ be a real number in $[1,\infty)$. Then, the following are equivalent.

1): $X$ is $L^p$-integrable.

2): $X^*_t= \mathop{\sup}_{0\leq s\leq t} |X_s|$ is $L^p$ integrable.

I would like to see a reference such that I can refer to it this theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Theorem 25.18 p168 in "Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions" by K-I Sato